# EXTJS RoW Widget - Old data get replaced by new data of Store

Tags: extjs, widget, store, expansion

I am working on `EXTJS`. I have issue in Row Widget which I have sued for expanding Grid. I have One Grid which displays data from one table and one expanding one of it's row the key is passed to display the expanded rows from another table having value same as that of passed key.

Issue i am facing is whenever use expands two rows then new data gets loaded and reflected in old expanded rows.

Let me know if anything else is required ?

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use [`alias:'store.storename'`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.Store.html) inside of store and inside of [`grid`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html) you need to use that store like below example :-

```
store:{
   type:'storealias'
}
```

So it will always create new instance for expanded grid.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2cl5)**, I have created a demo as you required. I hope this will guide/help you achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('ExpandStore', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            alias: 'store.expandstore',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data',
                    keepRawData: true
                }
            }
        })
        Ext.create({
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            title: 'Main Grid',
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            width: 600,
            height: 300,
            layout: 'fit',
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                data: [{
                    value1: 'Test 1',
                    id: 'Record one',
                    value2: 'Test 2'
                }, {
                    value1: 'Test 3',
                    id: 'Record two',
                    value2: 'Test 4'
                }]
            }),
            columns: [{
                dataIndex: 'value1',
                flex: 1,
                text: 'Column One'
            }, {
                dataIndex: 'value2',
                flex: 1,
                text: 'Column Two'
            }],
            listeners: {
                rowdblclick: 'onEfxAmendedTradesGridPanelIdRowDblClick'
            },
            plugins: [{
                ptype: 'rowwidget',
                onWidgetAttach: function (plugin, grid, record) {
                    var url = 'data1.json';
                    /*
                     * Herer I am putting condition on basis of record id
                     * In you case may you will call same url but diffrent id on server side so you Just need to send
                     * that id or may you will pas extra parameter inside of store
                     * For more details you can refer senha docs
                     */
                    if (record.get('id') == 'Record two') {
                        url = 'data2.json'
                    }
                    //if store is already loaded then no need to load again if you need you can remove this condition.
                    if (!grid.getStore().isLoaded()) {
                        grid.getStore().load({
                            url: url
                        })
                    }
                },
                rowBodyTpl: ['rowBodyTpl'],
                widget: {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    width: '100%',
                    autoLoad: false,
                    reference: 'AuditGridPanelRef',
                    scrollable: 'both',
                    bind: {
                        title: 'Expand ID is "{record.id}"'
                    },
                    store: {
                        type: 'expandstore' // it will create new instance of expandstore for every creation of grid
                    },
                    columns: [{
                        dataIndex: 'value1',
                        flex: 1,
                        text: 'Column One'
                    }, {
                        dataIndex: 'value2',
                        flex: 1,
                        text: 'Column two'
                    }]
                }
            }]
        })

    }
});
```

Comment: I can not see Alias Option in store properties.

Comment: Below are my sencha Architect Details: 
Version:
4.1.2.188
Channel:
4.1-stable
Platform:
1.2.8.4 - win32 x64
Renderer:
51.0.2704.106
Cmd:
6.2.2.36
Framework:
Ext JS 6.2.x Classic

Comment: Appreciate your effort for making working fiddle out of it and provide commented code though :)